# Does Boost.Serialization Free the Memory Created during Loading Pointers?

Tags: c++, boost-serialization

To be specific, I'm referring to the demo in Boost.Serialization tutorial [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/serialization/example/demo.cpp).

In the above demo, `bus_top` instances are stored as pointers in `bus_route` to showcase how serialization of pointers is achieved. However, I observed an interesting behavior, that is, the destructor `bus_stop::~bus_stop()` is never invoked for the `bus_stop` objects created by `restore_schedule()`. I put a break point in `bus_stop::~bus_stop()` and it was triggered only by the `delete` statements at the end of `main` function.

During loading serialized data, objects to initialize pointers are allocated in `pointer_iserializer` defined in `boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp`, which uses a `heap_allocator` to allocate space.

They do have a `destroy` function to release allocated memory in `boost/serialization/access.hpp`, but seems never got invoked.

Is it correct that Boost.Serialization does not manage the pointers created during loading data?

Comment: Where do you expect the destructors to be called?

Comment: @n.m. When the objects are freed. Actually I'm not expecting the pointers are going to be freed somewhere. I just feel strange that the demo just leave it out and no explain in the its document. There are other people think that the pointers will be freed automatically [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4122121/930095)

Comment: Those other people are seriously mistaken. No part of the deserialization machinery owns any part of deserialized object. I have no idea why such a thought would even cross anyone's head. "Loading the same pointer object multiple times results in only one object being created, thereby replicating the original pointer configuration". This says absolutely nothing about anything being owned by anything else. Bookkeeping during creation, yes. Ownerhip after creation... what kind of fantasy is it?

Comment: The documentation of delete_created_pointers says: "Deletes all objects created by the loading of pointers. This can be used to avoid memory leaks that might otherwise occur if pointers are being loaded and the archive load encounters an exception." What makes anyone think it is automatically called at any point after successful serialization?

Comment: Furthermore, automatic deletion of deserialized subordinate objects must require magic, as the archive has not a slightest idea as to when such deletion might be required or safely performed.

Comment: @n.m. You are right, but I'd say the document is rather obscure. They could have at least mentioned that the resources should be freed by `delete` by users themselves.

Comment: Well, they can also remind the users to brush their teeth twice a day while they're at it. Of course the user must free the resources. No one else can anyway. The demo has a leak, but that's only a shortcoming of the demo. It demonstrates deserialization of objects, not proper memory management. They have shared objects with plain pointers. Proper memory management of such objects would clutter the demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conclusions:

- The pointers are stored during loading and the objects they point to are created by `new` (i.e. `boost::archive::detail::heap_allocator`, `boost::serialization::access::construct`)
- There is also a `boost::serialization::access::destroy`, but AFAIK, it's not got invoked in `boost` anywhere.
- It's the user's duty to free the objects allocated by `boost::serialization`, using `delete` (or `boost::serialization::access::destroy` if you like).